# How to use resources from ResourceManager in WPF binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, resourcemanager

Is there any good tutorial on how to use ResourceManager in WPF binding ? I know how to use it with the GetString function to retrieve a specific resource, but I also would like to use in in binding.

something like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Resource.EnterName}"/>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binding would not do much except getting the value once as the resources do not provide any notifications as far as i know. You can get the values using [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx), e.g.:

```
<TextBlock xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:AppAssemblyName.Properties"
           Text="{x:Static prop:Resources.ResourceName}"/>
```

*(The resource's accessors need to be set to public)*

Comment: Tried it but I can't make it work... I don't seem to be able to get the 'prop' namespace as it doesn't let me do it

Comment: @DavidBrunelle: Did you set the access modifiers to public in the designer toolbar?

Comment: Nevermind I found what you are talking about (I wasn't the one who did the resource). Still, I can't get the 'Properties' part of the namespace to work

Comment: Just got it working... It was Resources, not Properties that I used but thanks. It's working now

Comment: I was just wondering. Do you think this could work with different cultures ? The reason we want this is to be able to translate the label for some user. The culture would be set before anything show.

Comment: @DavidBrunelle: It should work, as long as the properties are implemented as expected, getting the string using `ResourceManager.GetString(name, culture)`.

Comment: @H-B I'm at a lost here. I don't want to use a function GetString with a culture argument since it will be directly in the XAML... Does that mean it can't be done that way? I guess the best thing would be to test it.

Comment: @H-B Just tried it. It works like you mentionned at first. I have to change the resource culture before doing the initialiseComponents for now, so I guess there is a way to force the 'refresh' to prevent doing this.

Comment: @DavidBrunelle: If you have `.resx` resources the properties are automatically implemented using `GetString`, e.g. `Resource.EnterName` should look like this `public static string EnterName {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("EnterName", resourceCulture);
            }
        }` in the `Resource.Designer.cs` which is created automatically.